How can I get values of specific indexes for numpy array?
I have a numpy array (shape : (256, 256, 3)) of image and
I have numpy array for indexing as below.
array([[  3, 230],
       [  3, 231],
       [  3, 232],
       ...,
       [114, 151],
       [115, 149],
       [115, 150]], dtype=int64)

However, I want to get values of numpy array (shape : (256, 256, 3)) of image for
indexing as below. So that, I can get 3 channels values for specific index.
array([[  3, 230, :],
       [  3, 231, :],
       [  3, 232, :],
       ...,
       [114, 151, :],
       [115, 149, :],
       [115, 150, :]], dtype=int64)

How can I get values?

You can just index into the first two dimensions of the image array like so:
import numpy as np

# create an example image with different entries for each channel
image = (np.ones((256, 256)) * np.arange(3).reshape(3, 1, 1)).T

idx = np.asarray([[3, 230],
                  [3, 231],
                  [3, 232],
                  [114, 151],
                  [115, 149],
                  [115, 150]], dtype=np.int64)

values = image[idx[:, 0], idx[:, 1]]

print(values)

Which prints:
[[0. 1. 2.]
 [0. 1. 2.]
 [0. 1. 2.]
 [0. 1. 2.]
 [0. 1. 2.]
 [0. 1. 2.]]

I hope this helps!
